# meaning of this ocaml syntax

Tags: syntax, ocaml

I'm reading [lambdasoup/soup.ml at master · aantron/lambdasoup · GitHub](https://github.com/aantron/lambdasoup/blob/master/src/soup.ml) but I don't understand the syntax.

```
and 'a node =
  {mutable self   : 'b. 'b node option;
   mutable parent : general node option;
   values         : [ `Element of element_values
                    | `Text of string
                    | `Document of document_values ]}
```

I don't understand `'b. 'b node option`, if it was `*` it would be a tuple but it's the first time I see with `.` Also why the back-tic in the branches (e.g. `` `Element ``)?

Answer (score 3):

The type `'a . type` is a type that is explicitly polymorphic in `'a`. So your example `'b . 'b node option` is explcitly a field whose contents are polymorphic. In other words, any value assigned to the field must itself be polymorphic.

Here's an example with `list` rather than `node`:

```
type a = { mutable self : 'b. 'b list option; }
# let x  = { self = None };;
val x : a = {self = None}
# x.self <- None;;
- : unit = ()
# x.self <- Some [];;
- : unit = ()
# x.self <- Some [3];;
Error: This field value has type int list option
     which is less general than 'b. 'b list option
#
```

You can assign `None` to `x.self` because None is polymorphic (its type is `'a option`, which works for any option type). You can assign `Some []` to `x.self` because it's also polymorphic (its type is `'a list option`, which works for any optional list). But you can't assign `Some [3]` to `x.self` because its type is `int list option`; in other words, it's not polymorphic.

You can find a discussion of explicitly polymorphic types in [Section 5.2.1](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.10/polymorphism.html#s%3Apolymorphic-recursion) of the OCaml manual.

Variant values with leading backquote like `` `A `` or `` `B `` are so-called polymorphic variants. This is a different feature than the usual variant types. The basic idea is that a polymorphic variant represents a value that is not necessarily part of any predefined type. The associated types are essentially sets of these values. Polymorphic variants can also be constructors as in your example type; that is, they can take an associated value. Just as you can have `Some "yes"`, your definition allows one to have `` `Text "yes" ``.

You can find some discussion of polymorphic variants in [Section 7.4](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.10/types.html) of the OCaml manual (search for "polymorphic variant types").